# Fitting DialogFragment to image size

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment with a ViewPager that shows some pictures. The problem that there's a weird black stripe on top, and these pictures are deformed.

This is what I currently have, and as you can see, the picture doesn't really look good and there's a weird black stripe on top of the dialog.

[image]

This is how it should look, without black stripes and the picture fits the width of the screen.

[image]

How could I do this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you supply us with the xml your currently using as layout for the dialogfragment? If you are setting any custom theme in code please supply information about this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the imageview `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` or perhaps just setting the height of the viewpager and images to wrap_content.

Answer (score 5):

To get rid of the black frame at the top, try calling the `DialogFragment.setStyle(int style, int theme)` method in your `DialogFragment.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, e.g. `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0)` or `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0)`.

I'm also having problems like you getting a `DialogFragment` to be a certain width. The `layout_width` value of my `DialogFragment` (as specified in my `DialogFragment`'s xml layout file) seems to get overridden somewhere and sometimes my `DialogFragment` expands and sometimes it shrinks depending on the content. A bit of a hack I know but the best I've been able to come up with is to call the `getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(int width, int height)` method in my `DialogFragment.onResume()` method, e.g. `getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`.

To then resize your images to fit within your `DialogFragment`, use the `ImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType scaleType)` method as the other answers in this thread have alluded to.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the attribute `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your imageView